# ColVis doesn't work even with minimum configuration

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to get [ColVis](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/) option to work in my datatables.

My initialisation code is this (minimum configuration)

```
$('#'+id).dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip'
} );
```

But it does show the 'show/hide' button (no errors in console). See my table below:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this behavior? How can I debug and find where the problem is?

PS:

- Other addons like [TableTools](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html) work ok on this table.
- My JQuery version is 1.9.1
- My Datatables version is 1.9.4

**UPDATE**

- Updated my JQuery version to 1.10.1 but it doesn't solve the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had this problem. Try using your browser inspector to inspect element and then you'd be able to see if all the right classes have been added to the 'show / hide' button.

You should have this:
http://screencast.com/t/EEff9ti9zLKi

After clicking the 'show / hide' button to open the dropdown you would normally then get a bunch of extra data appended at the end of the document, right before < /body> It would look like this:
http://screencast.com/t/kQ70IxJg7j

Check to make sure that no html is being appended when you click the 'show / hide' (re: second screencast) that at least gives you a start into your debugging voyage.

For another sanity test you can try using an alternate ColVis.js file like this one: 
https://github.com/drewstaylor/colvis-extras/blob/master/colvis.extras.js

It was used to take those screencasts so you know it's working.